# How to get the List of Devices connected to the System

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, c#

Is there any way or tool with which I can generate a report which contains the Devices attached to the system along with their Vendor ID's and Device ID's ?

If there is no such tool, then can this be accomplished using the C# ?

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: @DavidPostill - Windows Operating System. Windows 8 onwards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF you are refering to the Windows system then you can simply access the device manager which lists all the devices which is connected to the computer.

To access the device manager in windows 7 just follow the following instructions

- Click on the Start button and then choose Control Panel.
- Click on the System and Security link.
- In the System and Security window, click on the Device Manager link located under the System heading.

If you are looking for a C# solution, without going into too much detail look into the following VMI classes

```
Win32_USBControllerDevice
Win32_SCSIControllerDevice
Win32_IDEControllerDevice
```

Comment: Is there any way to save the Device Manager info into Text File? I will take a look into those classes. Those should be WMI Classes right?

Comment: Yes they are VMI classes, also if you want to save device manager as a text file just follow this link http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/127156